# ¿ Puedo usar MySQL Server y a la vez PostgreSQL sin que haya conflictos de puertos u otros problemas?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, gvnix, spring-roo

Disculpa que os pregunte esto pero apenas tengo conocimiento en este tema.

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en Spring roo y gvNIX usando como IDE Eclipse.
He visto tutoriales que utilizan Postgre SQL para hacer determinadas acciones y ejemplos como usar componentes GEO , necesito instalarme MYSQL Server para poder gestionar la base de datos que utilice mi proyecto.

También me descargue WAMP Server para otras pruebas que hice con PHP en otros proyectos.

No sé si todo esto puede provocar alguna clase de problemas entre puertos u otros acontecimientos.

Answer (score 5):

> No sé si todo esto puede provocar alguna clase de problemas entre puertos u otros acontecimientos

Normalmente no. MySQL utiliza por defecto el puerto 3306 y PostgreSQL utiliza por defecto el puerto 5432. Asimismo, los servidores de aplicaciones en Java utilizan por defecto el puerto 8080 mientras que Apache utiliza por defecto el puerto 80. No deberías tener complicaciones al utilizar estas aplicaciones.

Sin embargo, considera que WAMP instala MySQL, puede que ya hayas instalado MySQL previamente, así que puedes obviar el módulo de MySQL que trae WAMP y utilizar el que ya tienes en configurado para evitar problemas.

Por último, en el extraño caso que surjan conflictos con los puertos, siempre puedes cambiar el puerto que utiliza la aplicación por defecto. Considera que en un ambiente de producción real lo mínimo que debes hacer con tus motores de base de datos es tenerlas instaladas en un servidor propio y posiblemente cambiar el puerto por defecto, así como cambiar las contraseñas de los usuarios administradores, por motivos de seguridad y de rendimiento.

Comment: 1 millón de gracias ! por tus sabias palabras !

Comment: +1 Quizás deberías aclarar que "Normalmente no" es respueta a la última frase de la pregunta, y no al título :-)

Answer (score 2):

Spring Roo genera aplicaciones Spring, por lo que perfectamente puedes utilizar 2 Datasources en tu aplicación.

http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/how-to-setup-multiple-data-sources-with-spring-and-jpa/

Espero que ayude.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda @eruiz !!! lo leeré con detenimiento !

Answer (score 0):

Disculpad mi falta de experiencia , acabo de darme cuenta , que al tener instalado `Wamp Server` puedo utilizar `Php MyAdmin` desde el navegador web para gestionar la base de datos `MySQL` que tienen instalada y utilizarla en las herramientas `Spring Roo` y `Gvnix` para almacenar los datos de mis proyectos.